# Issue in concatenating String in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a dynamic sql string. When I write this

```
DECLARE
    update_column VARCHAR2(20) := 'RED';
    update_statement VARCHAR2(50);

BEGIN
 -- update_column := 'RED';
    update_statement := 'UPDATE HEARTBEAT_REPORTING_DAILY SET '|| 
    UPDATE_COLUMN || ' = ' || UPDATE_COLUMN || ' + 20';   
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(update_statement);
END;
```

I get this error

```
Error starting at line 3 in command:
DECLARE
update_column VARCHAR2(20) := 'RED';
update_statement VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    update_statement := 'UPDATE HEARTBEAT_REPORTING_DAILY SET '|| 
    UPDATE_COLUMN || ' = ' || UPDATE_COLUMN || ' + 20';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(update_statement);
END;
Error report:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 5
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

But when I do this

```
DECLARE
    update_column VARCHAR2(20) := 'RED';
    update_statement VARCHAR2(50);

BEGIN
 -- update_column := 'RED';
    update_statement := 'UPDATE HEARTBEAT_REPORTING_DAILY SET '|| 
    UPDATE_COLUMN || ' = ' || UPDATE_COLUMN ||' +20';   
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(update_statement);
END;
```

it runs perfectly. Here is the output

```
UPDATE HEARTBEAT_REPORTING_DAILY SET RED = RED +20
```

Note that there was a space between ' +' and '20' in the previous and no space in the second. Why is this happening?

Comment: I counted 48 chars but perhaps you could increase the length of update_statement and see how you get on.

Comment: I tried your code and got the error: `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at line 6`... so... varchar(50) - too small.. increase it to 250 resolves your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, your string is 51 characters long and does not fit into the `VARCHAR2(50)` variable.

In the second case, there is a space less before "20". So the string is only 50 characters long and fits.

Increase your variable to a good length:

```
update_statement VARCHAR2(200);
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
update_statement := 'UPDATE HEARTBEAT_REPORTING_DAILY SET '|| 
    UPDATE_COLUMN || ' = ' || UPDATE_COLUMN || ' + 20';
```

Above line makes update_statement size as 51 but you have specified  update_statement as 50. That's the reason.

```sql
update_statement := 'UPDATE HEARTBEAT_REPORTING_DAILY SET '|| 
    UPDATE_COLUMN || ' = ' || UPDATE_COLUMN || ' +20';
```

In this case its size is exactly 50 so its accepting.